# Converting a completely customized design to SharePoint template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How do you convert a completely customized website to a SharePoint template.

1. Can it take the structure of a WordPress template?
2. Must it be asp or can PHP be integrated.
3. What is the most simplified way to do this

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: I'm using 2013 version

Comment: On Premise or SharePoint Online? Do you have enterprise license?

Comment: Yes I have enterprise licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 supports HTML master pages. You can create HTML file and then upload it into Design Manager. Design Manager will convert this file and associate it with `.master` file.

The structure of HTML file - You can take existing `seattle.html` or `oslo.html` file and create a copy. Then modify the copy by adding your content (`div`, `class`, `css`, `js` etc)

The above method is the most simplified way.

I am not sure about wordpress templates. But if you have basic HTML knowledge then you can easily grasp the layout used in the above mentioned HTML files.

SharePoint is built on top of ASP.Net. Hence the converted file (`.master`) is based on ASP.NET

You can use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx to read more about HTML master pages.

Comment: The files you refereed to in your second paragraph, where can they be found?

Comment: Open the site in sharepoint designer. Then go to Master Pages, there you can see those. Another option is to open the site in browser. Then click on the `gear` icon, then select `Design Manager`.